# django how to catch a variable of a form in template

Tags: python, django

I want to use feedback forms in my app. And I have FeedBack model and FeedBackForm form.

## models.py:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
comment = RichTextField()
```

## forms.py:

```
class FeedBackForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Feedback
    fields = ('name', 'email', 'comment')
```

I used FeedBackForm in my views,py file

## views.py

```
def home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    feedback_form = FeedBackForm(data=request.POST)
    if feedback_form.is_valid():
        feedback_form.save()
else:
    feedback_form = FeedBackForm()
return render(request, 'home.html', {'feedback_form': feedback_form})
```

Now my question is: how can I use my variables in template? Instead of this 3 input tags. (Is there another easier way other than

```
{{ feedbackform.as_p }}
```

and

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

to call my form variables "name", "email" and "comment" as input). Thanks in anvance

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: You're passing `feedback_form` into the template instead of `feedbackform`.  Aside from this small naming error, `{{ feedbackform.as_p }}` should work.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Sorry when I was writing question I made typpo!. (Actually I passed {{ feedback_form }} ) Are there another methods other than **feedback_form.as_p**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right, you want to call form.name, form.email and form.comment in template? See more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Yes this was what I am looking for. Thank you. And how can I add class to the "form.name" ? If it was common html tag it would be better but in this case is there any method to add class

Comment: I don't get why you would want to add class to form field form.name. If you want to get the entered variable "name" of the form in view, you can get it with formName = form.cleaned_data['name"].